# What should char function return in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, char, scanf

I'd like to know what should char function return?

Take this code for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *convert(char *str);

int main() {

    char *str[1000];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
    printf("\nOutput: %s\n", str);
    convert(str);
    printf("\nAfter converting to lowercase: %s\n\n", str);

    return 0;
}

char *convert(char *str) {

    int i = 0;
    char *p;
    char *c;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (p = c = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        *c = *p;
        if (*c < '0' || *c > '9') {
            c++;
        }
    }
    *c = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

I'm returning *str* in char *convert function but this code works fine even if I don't return anything or return 0. Should I change this function to void? Is this code alright?

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings - you have at least one very obvious bug that the compiler will happily warn you about if you let it.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value in your call, so it doesn't matter what you return.

Comment: `char *str[1000];` Do you really want an *array of pointers to char* (1000 of them), or do you want an *array of char*, say `char str[1000] = "";` that can store a string up to `999 char + 1 nul-terminator`??

Answer (score 1):

**Should I change this function to void? Is this code alright?**

You always want to match the return type of the function to how your function is intended to be used. There is nothing wrong returning `char *` from `convert`. Since you do not alter the address of `str` within `convert`, that provides the option of using the return as a parameter to another function, such as:

```
printf("\nAfter converting to lowercase: %s\n\n", convert (str));
```

If you had declared `convert` as `void`, that would no longer be an option. However, by returning `str`, you also lose the ability to change where `str` points within the function. (so for example in converting to lowercase, you couldn't simply increment `str++` in your function) Not a limitation, just something to be aware of. Really, either way is fine.

As for your `convert` function itself, it does not compress the spaces on either side of the digits it removes in `str`. For example, if you enter the string:

```
My dog HAS 23 Fleas
```

as input, you receive:

```
my dog has  fleas
```

as output with the double-space (on from either side of `23` still present in the string. You can clean that up by adding a flag tracking consecutive spaces or by adding additional tests.

The final comment I would have would be to refactor your `convert` into two functions, one to convert to lowercase (say `str2lower`) and one to remove digits (say `strrmdigits`). The allows you to reuse the functions independently. There are many times you will want to convert to lowercase, and maybe a few you want to remove digits, but there will be very few times you want to both convert to lowercase and remove the digits from a string. So think ahead when factoring your code.

A splitting of your `convert` into a `str2lower` and `strrmdigits` could go something like follows:

```
char *str2lower (char *str)  /* convert string to lower case */
{
    for (char *p = str; *p; p++)
        if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z')
            *p ^= ('A' ^ 'a');    /* works for ASCII & EBCDIC */

    return str;
}
```

The function to remove digits while compressing surrounding whitespace into one, could look like:

```
char *strrmdigits (char *str)   /* remove included digits */
{
    char *p = str;      /* pointer used to elminate digits */
    int nspace = 0;     /* flag tracking consequtive spaces */

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)    /* loop over each char */
        if (str[i] < '0' || '9' < str[i]) { /* digit? */
            if (str[i] != ' ') {    /* if not a space */
                *p++ = str[i];      /* write character */
                nspace = 0;         /* set space count 0 */
            }   /* otherwise */
            else if (!nspace) {     /* no space written yet? */
                *p++ = str[i];      /* write space */
                nspace = 1;         /* set space written flag */
            }
        }

    *p = 0;     /* nul-terminate at p */

    return str;
}
```

You could then tidy up your test program a bit by removing the *magic number* `1000` and using a proper `#define` to define the needed constant. (don't use magic numbers in your code). While `fgets` is a better choice for user input (you simply trim the trailing '\n'), if you are going to use `scanf`, then you must always **validate the return**, and when reading strings into an array, **always protect your array bounds** by including a proper *field width* modifier to specify the maximum number of characters to read. (there is no way around it, you cannot use a variable, so the field width is a value you have to hardcode.)

With those tweaks included, you could do something like the following (making use of the return from each of the functions), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1000   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

char *str2lower (char *str);
char *strrmdigits (char *str);

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC] = "";                /* initialize all strings zero */

    printf ("Enter a string: ");
    if (scanf ("%999[^\n]s", str) != 1) {   /* always validate return */
        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("\nOutput: '%s'\n\n", str);

    printf ("to lowercase  : '%s'\n\n", str2lower (str));
    printf ("digits removed: '%s'\n", strrmdigits (str));

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/charrtn
Enter a string: My dog HAS 23 Fleas

Output: 'My dog HAS 23 Fleas'

to lowercase  : 'my dog has 23 fleas'

digits removed: 'my dog has fleas'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.